# Elastic search edge_ngram match query on _all being ignored

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I'm using elastic search `number: "1.5.2"` and I'm trying to implement an edge_ngram autocomplete search. I have the following mapping:

```js
curl -XPUT 'localhost:8080/users' -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "edge_ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "edge_ngram_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "whitespace_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "user": {
                "_all": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "index_analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "id":{
                        "type": "integer",
                        "index": "no",
                        "include_in_all":false
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "firstName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "lastName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I then index an "user" document:

```js
curl -XPUT 'localhost:8080/users/user/1' -d '{
    "email": "a.smith@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "Alexander",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}'
```

When I run the following query nothing is returned:

```js
curl -XGET 'localhost:8080/users/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "match":{
            "_all":{
                "query": "ale",
                "operator":"and"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Why is the _all match query not matching on the user document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the functionality of autocomplete by edge_ngram without overriding the `_all` field analysis. This is done by changing the names of the analyzers you have defined to `default_index` and `default_search`  (you can [alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html#aliasing-analyzers) them to reflect your original names ("edge_ngram_analyzer" and "whitespace_analyzer") if you want). Here is your configuration with the relevant changes:

```js
curl -XPUT 'localhost:8080/users' -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "edge_ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "default_index": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "edge_ngram_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "default_search": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "user": {
                "properties": {
                    "id":{
                        "type": "integer",
                        "index": "no",
                        "include_in_all":false
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "firstName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "lastName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Hope I have managed to help :)

Comment: This worked beautifully. Simple and elegant solution. Thank you!