# How can I score Elasticsearch matches for particular field names higher when using a full text search on _all?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've setup an index that has many types representing user data such as a ShoppingList, Playlist, etc. Each type has an "identity_id" field for the user's unique identifier. I use the following query to search across all types and fields for a user (for a search function in a website):

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
          "_all": "awesome"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "identity_id": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to give a higher score to matches on fields that have "name" in the field name? For example, the ShoppingList type will have a shopping_list_name field, and I want a match on that to be higher than its other fields.
2. Is the above way of doing a full text search for a particular user (query then filter) the most efficient way? What about creating an index per user?

Comment: For anyone interested, I ended up using this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082797/elastic-search-edge-ngram-match-query-on-all-being-ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this query that boosts certain fields:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "awesome",
          "fields": [
            "*_name",
            "field*"
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "weight": 2,
          "filter": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "awesome",
              "fields": [
                "*_name"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "weight": 1,
          "filter": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "awesome",
              "fields": [
                "field*"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What the query above does is to boost (`weigth: 2`) the `*_name` fields query and not do apply any boosting to fields called `field*`.

> Is the above way of doing a full text search for a particular user (query then filter) the most efficient way? What about creating an index per user?

Regarding this ^ question, that's more complicated and you also need to consider how many users you have, the hardware resources the cluster has, structure of data, queries used etc.

Comment: Very interesting solution, thanks! Although I get this error when I try it:

            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"awesome\""

It looks like it's trying to interpet the query as a number? I'm using ElasticSearch 2.3.2

Comment: Well, yes, if your `*_name` or `field*` fields are numeric fields.